CXSYNC_PORT & "Long running low CPU"
I have a simple query like select * from MyTable where MyTableID=@p1where sp_BlitzCache warns me about "Long Running with Low CPU". The table has a clustered index on MyTableID, which is a uniqueidentifier/GUID.
Can this be caused by executing the statement too frequent?
Yes, this is Entity Framework, and we're trying to make it go faster, without changing the C# code too much (as it takes a long time).
Currently running at vCores = 80, and that is "a bit" expensive.
I have tried to follow https://www.brentozar.com/blitzcache/long-running-low-cpu/, but the guidelines are not crystal clear to me. 
sp_whoisactive shows a lot of statements with Async_Network_IO
sp_BlitzFirst shows CXSYNC_PORT as the major wait type, by far, but I cannot find any info on this, and I do not know if it is related to this query, or one of the many other queries running.
I've tried to find an execution plan, but sp_BlitzIndex only shows the SQL statement. But given that, I get this plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r11D40QQ0

It has been executed 13.441.177 times on my test server that has been up for 55 hours.

Why do I get "Long running low CPU" and how do I fix that?

I also see simple INSERTs and UPDATEs getting this label.
Can all these "Long running low CPU" be caused by a slow disk?

where MyTableID=@p1 on the unique index should be a simple index seek. It shouldn't be going parallel at all. If that is going parallel is there a data type mismatch causing a scan?

Though I just noticed the plan link that you have formatted as code for some reason - this shows that the parameter is mismatched (varchar(8000)) but this is not problematic as the parameter is cast to uniqueidentifier rather than the column being cast so doesn't prevent a seek. The plan is serial though so not correlated with any CXSYNC_PORT waits. It is unclear that this query is really causing any actual problem.

If your objective here is to scale down to less than 80 vCores then why are you running at 80 vCores? What resource are you finding inadequate at lower? If it is CPU then use query store to identify the most CPU intensive queries on aggregate and then look at those

The CXSYNC_PORT wait is a subcategory of CXPACKET wait and related synchronizing opening/closing of exchange port between consuming thread and producing thread. Long waits here may indicate server load and lack of available threads.
Could you please try to avoid returning all columns of the table (*) as result of the query, return only the columns needed and create an index like the one below to support that query.
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_MyTable_MyTableId_Includes]
ON [dbo].[MyTable] ([MyTableId])
INCLUDE (Col1, Col2, Col3, etc.)


hi Alberto,
Thank you for the info about "lack of available threads". Yes, the server is loaded. Is it possible to get more Threads? Not as far as I can Google it.
I cannot do a covering index here, as C# needs the XML data column.

Please consider storing that XML data on a separate table. Join the tables by Inner Join on the MyTableId. Create XML indexes if you need to query that XML data later.

Hi Alberto, yes, that is a good idea. I'll forward that to the C# team

Hope that solves the issue.
